# How to add each element (sentence) of a list to a pandas column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am extracting information about chemical elements from Wikipedia. It contains sentences, and I want each sentence to be added as follows:

| Molecule | Sentence1 | Sentence1 and sentence2 | All_sentence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MgO | this is s1. | this is s1. this is s2. | all_sentence |
| CaO | this is s1. | this is s1. this is s2. | all_sentence |

What I've achieved so far

```
import spacy
import pandas as pd
import wikipediaapi
import csv


wiki_wiki = wikipediaapi.Wikipedia('en')
chemical = input("Write the name of molecule: ")

page_py = wiki_wiki.page(chemical)
sumary = page_py.summary[0:]

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

text_sentences = nlp(sumary)
sent_list = []
for sentence in text_sentences.sents:
    sent_list.append(sentence.text)


#print(sent_list)


df = pd.DataFrame(
   {'Molecule': chemical,
     'Description': sent_list})
print(df.head())
```

The output looks like:

| Molecule | Description |
| --- | --- |
| MgO | All sentences are here |
| Mgo |  |

The Molecule columns are shown repeatedly for each line of sentence which is not correct.
Please suggest some solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you would want to repeat all sentences in each column but you can get to the form you want with `pivot`:

```
import spacy
import pandas as pd
import wikipediaapi
import csv


wiki_wiki = wikipediaapi.Wikipedia('en')
chemical = input("Write the name of molecule: ")

page_py = wiki_wiki.page(chemical)
sumary = page_py.summary[0:]

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

sent_list = [sent.text for sent in nlp(sumary).sents]
#cumul_sent_list = [' '.join(sent_list[:i]) for i in range(1, len(sent_list)+1)] # uncomment to cumulate sentences in columns

df = pd.DataFrame(
   {'Molecule': chemical,
     'Description': sent_list}) # replace sent_list with cumul_sent_list if cumulating
df["Sentences"] = pd.Series([f"Sentence{i + 1}" for i in range(len(df))]) # replace "Sentence{i+1}" with "Sentence1-{i+1}" if cumulating
df = df.pivot(index="Molecule", columns="Sentences", values="Description")
print(df)
```

`sent_list` can be created using a list comprehension. Create `cumul_sent_list` if you want your sentences to be repeated in columns.

Output:

```
Sentences                                          Sentence1  ...                                          Sentence9
Molecule                                                      ...                                                   
MgO        Magnesium oxide (MgO), or magnesia, is a white...  ...  According to evolutionary crystal structure pr...
```

Comment: it gives me this error `or magnesia, is a white...[1 rows x 8 columns]Exception ignored in: <function Wikipedia.__del__ at 0x7f5ef530bb80>Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/anaconda3/envs/wiki-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wikipediaapi/__init__.py", line 170, in __del__File "/ana/envs/wiki/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 747, in close
envs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py"packages/urllib3/_collections.py", line 95, in clearTypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: The problem seems to be with the `wikipediaapi`, do you have another instance running?

Comment: In the case of `MgO` output should be [1 rows x 10 columns]

Comment: yes, but I want it to show the first sentence in first column, in the second column s1+s2 and on the 3rd column, all the output. I am not sure how to do. you code create columns based on the number of sentences. but I want only three columns for first sentence, first and seconde sentence, and finally all sentence in the last column.

Comment: Checkout the comments in the code I Integrated this solution as well ;)

Comment: I checked it, but your code create column based on the number of sentences. I don't want this. Furthermore, I want only three columns. Colum1⇾Sentence1, Column2⇾sentence1 + sentence2, and Column3⇾ All the sentences.

Comment: Then define `cumul_sent_list = [sent_list[0], ' '.join(sent_list[:2]), ' '.join(sent_list)]` and adjust `df["Sentences"]` to your expected columns